# Android leftMargin is not moving, but expanding view. How can I move it?

Tags: android, gallery, translate

I have 4 images in a linear horizontal view. Using the XML I have made it that the first image will fit to width of screen at start. I have left / right arrows, so when I tap on right arrow I would like to translate the horizontal layout to see previous / next picture.

My idea was to change the margin of the entire  layout so that it moves. However, when I change the left margin, it just expands the first image to outside the screen, to the left.
Why is this happening, how can I translate the entire thing and not get this expanding effect?

Below, my XML and my java:

```
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/HomeGallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/innerHomeGallery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButtonHomeGallery1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/topimg12x"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null" /> 
         <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButtonHomeGallery2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/topimg22x"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null" />
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButtonHomeGallery3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/topimg32x"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null" />
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButtonHomeGallery4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/topimg42x"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null" />
                </LinearLayout> 
            </LinearLayout>
```

..........

```
LinearLayout innerHomeGallery  = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.innerHomeGallery);

    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams contentParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)innerHomeGallery.getLayoutParams();

    contentParams.leftMargin=-600;

    innerHomeGallery.setLayoutParams(contentParams);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to implement a design where user will be able to navigate between images through arrow keys left and right, then try using ViewPager, or for more basic follow this.

1. Keep  frame layout as your root view, add Imageview of whatever dimension you want as first child
2. You can add two more child as left and right navigation button to the framelayout.

now implement onClick listeners for both of the button, now just add code for setting proper image to ImageView on respective button clicks. You can also add in animations different animations like fade in or our to make it look cooler.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already have arrows, besides the code in my post, that is not the problem. I know how tho do an onclick listner and it done, but I do not want to assign a different image to one image view, because i want the images to slide in and out. Not just change. So any idea on how to do that? What about animating the change, that would be my next question..

Comment: Use ViewPager then, there you can easily provide in and out animations. Its very simple, Just like an listview, create an pageadapter hook it to flipper provide in and out animations, and keep flipping view via your control buttons.

Comment: The ViewFlipper made everything fall into place. Exactly what I needed. Good hint.